# stingray - trafficscript without change the URL

Tags: javascript, php, node.js

I have the following code :-

```
$hostheader = http.getHostHeader();
$path = http.getPath();
$languages = [‘cs’, ‘cs-cs’, ‘pt’, ‘pt-pt’, ‘fi’, ‘fi-fi’, ‘sl’, ‘sl-sl’, ‘el’, ‘el-gr’, ‘sr’, ‘sr-sr’, ‘ro’, ‘ro-ro’, ‘hu’, ‘hu-hu’, ‘es’, ‘sv’, ‘de’, ‘de-de’, ‘cn’, ‘zh’, ‘zh-cn’, ‘ru’, ‘ru-ru’, ‘fr’, ‘fr-fr’, ‘pl’, ‘pl-pl’, ‘at’, ‘ja’, ‘ja-jp’, ‘zh-hk’, ‘de-at’];
if ($hostheader == “website” ) {
   foreach($lang in $languages) { 
   if (string.endsWithI($path, $lang) ) {
      http.setResponseHeader(“Host”, “host”);
      http.setHeader(“Host”, “host” . $lang);  
      if(!ssl.isSSL()) {  
        pool.use(“cms-splash-https-Pool”);
      }
      else {
       pool.use(“cms-splash-http-Pool”);
      }
   }
  }
}


if( http.getHostHeader() == "host" ) {
 http.changeSite( "newwebsite" );
}
```

I want to redirect without change the URL so no one will notice anything , is this possible ?

Comment: If that is your actual code, all of the `“` (curly quotes) need to be regular ones `"`. Same thing for `‘` which should be `'`.

Comment: I know , but because of copying the code it's changed